# Locking an object off so that properties must first be defined before being assigned to

Tags: php

I am aware that I can do this:

```
/**
 * This prevents people from adding properties on the fly
 */
interface ILockProperties {
    function __set( $field, $value );
}

class Sausage extends OtherRequiredStuff implements ILockProperties
{
    public $DefinedProperty;

    public function __set( $field, $value )
    {
        throw new Exception( "This property does not exist" );
    }
}

$sausage = new Sausage();
$sausage->DefinedProperty = "shoop"; // Will be fine
$sausage->NotThere = "something";  // Will throw error
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

At the very least, is there a way of checking across both the extended classes and the current class when the set is called?

Comment: Not in PHP there isn't.

Comment: Cheers Erik, it's a complete nightmare on this big project, everyone keeps adding properties! And now I have to enforce that we implement this interface to stop that noobness. #php :(

Comment: The downside to freedom in a language is people using it. The only real answer is code review and enforcing rules I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately PHP objects don't inherit from a root object; if so, you could simply declare a final `__set()` method and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is the following, have your parent class declare a magic method called `__set( $key $value )`, and then throw an error

```
class OtherRequiredStuff
{
    public function __set( $key, $value )
    {
        throw new Exception("Cant set me, haha");
    }
}

class Child extends OtherRequiredStuff
{

}

$child = new Child();
$child->age = 16;
```

Comment: As Jack also said, this seems to be the only way of doing it.

Perhaps for our next project, we will extend all of our classes from a CoreObject.

Thanks